# Dynamic partials in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an angular app that lists items for the user to service, sort of a to-do list.  Each to-do requires different fields to complete the task.  Making the to-do list is simple.  My question is how do I have each to-do item expand to reveal a different set of "sub-partials"?  See diagram below:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| To do #1                                                |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| To do #2                                                |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| To do #3                                                |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

User clicks to expand the first to-do:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| To do #1                                                |
|                                                         |
| +--------------+  +--------------+  +--------------+    |
| | partial A    |  | partial B    |  | partial C    |    |
| +--------------+  +--------------+  +--------------+    |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| To do #2                                                |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| To do #3                                                |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

User expands 2nd to-do:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| To do #1                                                |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| To do #2                                                |
|                                                         |
| +--------------+  +--------------+  +--------------+    |
| | partial A    |  | partial D    |  | partial E    |    |
| +--------------+  +--------------+  +--------------+    |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| To do #3                                                |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Typically one of the sub-partials might have 3-10 fields.  Notice some of them are re-used but some will be different in each to-do item.  I expect to have about 30 of the sub-partials.

Is something like this possible to do in a clean way in Angular?  I've been looking at ui-router but I don't know that it can do a different set for each to-do.  Is there another approach or something better for this?  Any suggestions are welcome.

I'd also like to dynamically load the controllers if possible, but that's secondary to the main goal.

If necessary I could have the selected to-do with sub-partials appear in a modal pop-up dialog instead of expanding.

Answer (score 1):

What I've done in my last app is set the name of the sub-partial I want to load as a `$scope` variable, and then use that variable in an `ng-include`.

```
.when('/team/:team', {
      'template': "<div ng-include=\"nav.template\"></div>",
      'controller': 'TeamCtrl',
 }
```

Then in my controller somewhere:

```
$scope.nav.template = 'app/partials/team/' + $routeParams.team + '.html';
```

This let me expand the number of teams who wanted a link quickly without changing my code and adding every team individually. I'm thinking this logic can be expanded to fit your requirement.

Notice that in my example the whole thing is set in the router, but you can also do this from your controller, and set the dynamic `ng-include` inside another partial.

Comment: So that gets the HTML in but you're left with having a controller that must handle all the sub-partials?  I'm imagining kind of a mess there for me.  I'd like to reuse the partials elsewhere so keeping each with it's own separate controller as much as possible would be nice.

Comment: Yeah. My partials are all the same though, with different content so it's not an issue. I'm sorry it's not useful to you.

Comment: Well I forgot I can specify the controller with the sub-partial, it becomes a child of main partial.  So between that and ng-include, I think I can make it work.  Hopefully 2.0 fixes this.